# Attaching a laptop to a table

Tags: piece-information, building

I want to give my minifigs a few laptops. Specifically, [62698 "minifigure utensil, laptop"s](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62698):

[image: minifig utensil, laptop]

I've seen laptops in sets and MOCs, but always either (a) closed, being held in a minifig hand or clip, or (b) open, laying on top of a tiled surface (like a desk), unattached.

**But instead** I want the laptop to lay *securely* on top of a table/desk while open. By "securely" I mean "if I shake the model, the laptop should remain in place" (no need for technic-level sturdiness).

AFAIK, an open laptop is too thin to be held by a clip, and has no obvious way of fitting over studs. What technique(s) can I use to *attach* an open laptop to a table?

Comment: If you're not limited to pure LEGO solutions, a tiny piece of blu-tac rolled flat could work?

Comment: I would like to avoid adhesives. Besides, blu-tac doesn't qualify as [tag:building] :-D

Comment: Do rubber bands count as building? A Technic plate underneath with a rubber band through the holes would surely be sturdy enough for a little shake.

Comment: Rubber band was first thing on my mind too, but they rarely come in Black color. There are some larger size, but they are a little pricey. Maybe [string with end studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x127c11) could be used to instead of rubber band.

Comment: I guess I could use sewing thread. Put laptop on top of 2x2 tile, wrap sewing thread around both, place tile on studs, thread underneath tile gets stuck. But I was hoping for a solution which doesn't involve flexible parts (or folded used sticker sheets, for that matter)

Comment: You can use elements with clips to hold the laptop on 2 or 3 sides so it won't move when shaken.

Comment: I can't test this idea as I don't own that laptop piece, but wouldn't the flat circular end of a minfig lever / antenna fit into the front slot of the laptop?

Comment: @zovits I just tested that out in LeoCAD and, in theory, there's a fit. The width of the laptop is roughly equal to the width of the lever base gap (less than 1 LDU difference, in any case). I think it's also possible to clip the screen part of the laptop (AKA top half) to a lever base. I currently lack a lever to test this physically.